# intel drivers - Tearing all over the place on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics, screen-tearing

getting horrible video tearing on WIN7 64 bit using Intel Iris Graphics 6100. Tearing occues in Youtube, VLC, Smplayer) I have the Intel Graphics Control Panel application and have tried adjusting:

refresh rates : 60, 60i, 59 and matching screen refresh rates. 
enabled/disabled application control of Vsync 
changed to OPEN GL in both VLC and SMplayer

I'm nt sure what the issue is. This is an Intel Iris Graphics 6100 which runs very smoothly on Ubuntu without tweaking anything.

The only thing I havent done during all of this is restarting my computer after changes were made, but i enver read anywhere that this was imperative.

Comment: Perhaps uninstalling and reinstalling the Intel drivers is a good idea. I did just recently do a whole bunch of Windows updates... do you think that might have corrupted some of the Intel drivers? also dxdiag.exe showed no problems.

Comment: I forgot , The easy test for your grafics to see if they are functioning proper (with dxdiag) is to do the system assessment. Improper it would show your grafics at about 1, proper you should hit at least 4 with even lesser intel.  Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Performance Information and Tools

Comment: 6.9 on subcore list for Graphics

Comment: Ok, back to v-sync issue. comment cleanup.  The aero desktop is supposed to enforce V-sync, your not having any issues there?  Can you get a good clean version of MPC (media player classic) to try?  with it not only can you adjust sync, but you can test other renderers (3d or 2d) ? it also has a "tearing" test.

Comment: Okay I installed in PC and really tearing test. all I saw were red lines going across the screen there was no output or conclusion to the test... Was I supposed to let it run longer? PS - it was still tearing

Comment: nope it just displays the tearing easy to see. then in options -> playback ->output  there is many ways to adjust. like try the "overlay mixer" , you Must stop and restart program when changing renderers. Uhh whats this supposed to prove?  test 2d , 3d and overlay. does it happen in all of them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40688/discussion-between-kalamalka-kid-and-psycogeek).

Answer (score 2):

After installing numerous multimedia programs and fiddling around with the settings, uninstalling the Intel drivers and reinstalling the Intel drivers, and messing around with refresh rates and other driver related tweets, I was unable to get rid of the tearing.

The only solution I have found so far is to change the Windows theme to an Aero theme. A detailed explanation of why this Aero theme solution works can be seen [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/558007/how-does-windows-aero-prevent-screen-tearing)

If you still want to have the functionality of Aero (no tearing), but still want a custom background, make sure you first choose an Aero theme, and then change the background afterwards (this will apply your background change to the selected theme).

If your Windows verision does not include Aero there is a fix [HERE](http://www.askvg.com/download-simple-patch-to-enable-aero-glass-and-all-other-personalization-features-in-windows-7-home-basic-and-starter-edition/)